# Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, backend, create-react-app

I'm having trouble integrating firebase with my React app. I used create-react-app to make the app and have an express backend.

So far I've added:

```
<!-- Firebase Services -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

<!-- ReactFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/reactfire/1.0.0/reactfire.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var config = {
        apiKey: "***********************",
        authDomain: "****************",
        databaseURL: "******************",
        projectId: "***********",
        storageBucket: "*************",
        messagingSenderId: "***********"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

To my index.html, and have tried `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` inside a component in order to call

```
   handleSubmit(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           firebase.auth()
           .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.emailValue, 
            this.state.passValue)
           .catch((error) => {
               console.error(error)
           })
       }
```

Along with:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
if (user) {
    console.log('user logged in')
} else {
    console.log('not logged in')
}})
```

But's giving me the error stated in the title.

I'm not sure why this is happening, and also not sure if I'm integrating firebase with my React app correctly?

Am I supposed to use ReactFire alone, or do I still configure it like they say in the docs for user Authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to create a separate firebase file in say a lib folder like so.

```
//lib/fire.js
import firebase from 'firebase'
const config = {
        apiKey: "***********************",
        authDomain: "****************",
        databaseURL: "******************",
        projectId: "***********",
        storageBucket: "*************",
        messagingSenderId: "***********"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const db = firebase.database()
export const auth = firebase.auth()
```

Then in my component...

```
//component.js
import React from 'react'
import {auth} from '../lib/fire'
export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      pass: ''
    }
  }
  handleLogin() {
    const { email, pass } = this.state
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(user => {
      <do something with user>
    }).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>... form stuffs </div>
    )
  }
}
```

obviously you'll need to handle the form inputs and everything but my point is that you should / can use the auth or database in this manner. This seems to be the universally accepted way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing Firebase init javascript file because of which firebase.initializeApp(config) is not working. Apart from the individual firebase services you need to get the init file too. You can refer the sample application listed here for the same: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/email.html#L35